# Laravel 5.2 retrieve specific fields from database

Tags: database, eloquent, laravel-5

Basically im pulling all user details with `User::where('archived', false)->get();`i would like to know how i would only retrieve the specific fields `user_name, user_id, user_age` etc.. because right now its pulling all the fields, is there a way to do this using Laravels eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User::select('user_id', 'user_name', 'user_age')->get();`

Comment: Haha i just figured out the get bit wasnt sure if it needed it thanks a tonne btw for this!

Comment: No problem, if its correct, please tick as answer so other people can benefit from this :)

Answer (score 0):

For specific columns:

```
$user = User::select('user_id', 'user_name', 'user_age')
            ->get();
```

// or

```
 $user = User::get('user_id', 'user_name', 'user_age');
```